# Filter data from 2 tables and get results from both tables

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How can I filter data-set in 2 Tables where second table have more results 1:n.

In first table I can use orWhere and I am getting right data, but my another Table contain multiple results and if I use contain or matching I am getting only data from second Table.

So, I want to filter both tables and get matched data.

Here is my query:

First query to filter first table

```
$query
      ->where([
        'OR' => [
          'Orders.id' => $freeText,
          'Orders.postal' => $freeText,
          'Orders.address LIKE' => '%' . $freeText . '%',
          'Orders.city LIKE' => '%' . $freeText . '%',
          'Users.first_name' => $freeText,
          'Users.last_name' => $freeText,
          'ProjectAddresses.cost_centre' => $freeText,
          'CONCAT(first_name, last_name) LIKE' => '%' . str_replace(' ', '', $freeText) . '%',
          'CONCAT(first_name, last_name) LIKE' => '%' . $freeText . '%',
          'Users.first_name IN ' => $splittedKeywords,
          'Users.last_name IN ' => $splittedKeywords,
        ]
      ]);
```

Second query - try to filter data from second Table (but still need matched data from first table)

```
$query->contain('Items', function ($q) use ($freeText) {
    return $q->where(['vessel_id' => $freeText]);
});
```

So problem is if I use second query he automatically take only data from second table and my goal is to get all filtered data (from first and second table).

I have 20+ data-sets like:

```
(int) 0 => [
        'id' => (int) 1,
        'uuid' => '5f34ecda-6bc6-46ed-b5cc-b2227029aed8',
        'user_id' => (int) 319,
        'status' => (int) 30,
        'order_price' => (float) 341.04,
        'address_id' => (int) 379,
        'address' => 'XYZ',
        'building_number' => '171',
        'postal' => '111',
        'city' => 'XYZ',
        'country' => 'AT',
        'project_address' => [
            'id' => (int) 379,
            'type' => 'project',
            'group_id' => (int) 3,
            'default' => false,
            'corresponding_invoice_address' => null,
            'short_name' => 'XYT',
            'comment' => '',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'id' => (int) 319,
            'uuid' => '675216eb-7110-44d2-82a7-f7f020e934a6',
            'title' => 'Herr',
            'first_name' => 'Test',
            'last_name' => 'Test',
        ],
        'item_groups' => [],
        'items' => [
            (int) 0 => [
                'id' => (int) 26,
                'uuid' => 'f4f629be-e25e-4432-8d97-6b2adcee9065',
                'item_group_id' => null,
                'type' => (int) 2,
                'status' => (int) 30,
                'vessel_id' => (int) 40001,
                'features' => [],
            ],
            (int) 1 => [
                'id' => (int) 28,
                'uuid' => 'f4f629be-e25e-4432-8d97-6b2adcee9065',
                'item_group_id' => null,
                'type' => (int) 2,
                'status' => (int) 30,
                'vessel_id' => (int) 40003,
                'features' => [],
            ],
            (int) 1 => [
                'id' => (int) 29,
                'uuid' => 'f4f629be-e25e-4432-8d97-6b2adcee9065',
                'item_group_id' => null,
                'type' => (int) 2,
                'status' => (int) 30,
                'vessel_id' => (int) 40003,
                'features' => [],
            ],
        ]
    ],
```

SQL

```
SELECT *
FROM orders Orders
INNER JOIN users Users ON Users.id = (Orders.user_id)
LEFT JOIN addresses ProjectAddresses ON ProjectAddresses.id = (Orders.address_id)
WHERE (Orders.id = :c0
       OR Orders.postal = :c1
       OR Orders.address LIKE :c2
       OR Orders.city LIKE :c3
       OR Users.first_name = :c4
       OR Users.last_name = :c5
       OR ProjectAddresses.cost_centre = :c6
       OR CONCAT(first_name, last_name) LIKE :c7
       OR Users.first_name IN (:c8)
       OR Users.last_name IN (:c9))
```

Parameter is `c1 = 4001 || %40001% || %40001`

@ndm The goal is If somebody send in `$freeText == 40003` I have to get as result this object where `vessel_id = 40003` and thats works, but if somebody send in `$freeText == Test` then I need again same result because `first_name == Test` 8see first query) and when in second wuery I am using matching/contain this results are removed because he only "fetch" rows that are matching/contain Items...

Basically I want to check 10+ columns with given $freeText variable and if it is matching I want that results in my data-set (from both tables)

Comment: "_So problem is if I use second query he automatically take only data from second table_" With the relation you're describing, I don't really see how this could happen. Contained associations should only be able to reduce the results of the main query in case of `1:1` or `n:1` relations that are using `INNER` joins. Please show some (debugging) results, like the generated SQL, the retrieved data vs the expected data, ...

Comment: @ndm I have updated my question...

Comment: I still don't really get it. You seem to describe the exact opposite of what you are showing. I can see how `Items` could be missing when querying for `Test` instead of `40003`, and I could see how orders could be missing when querying for `40003` instead of `Test`, but not the other way around. Matching is a different story, but you're showing contain here, and the main query isn't affected by that according to the shown SQL.

Comment: Let's try a different route... could it be that you are looking for filtering `Orders` based on possible matching `Items`, ie include `Orders` that have associated `Items` that **do match `X`**, even if in turn **`X` does not match** in `Orders`, `Users`, or `ProjectAddresses`, and vice versa, include all associated `Items` even if **`X` only matches** in `Orders`, `Users`, or `ProjectAddresses`?

Comment: @ndm yes, like it is described in the last sentence of my my question

Comment: I have similair problem, I have tried with union but it doesn´t work. If I use matching/contain I am getting results only from (matching/contain table). But description from @ndm is what I actually need - send $var and filter  results everywhere where $var == column_content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, then you're looking for a left join filter, ie left join `Items` (additionally to containing it for retrieval), group by `Orders` primary key (to avoid duplicates), and then simply add the `Items.vessel_id` condition to the main queries `WHERE` clause in order to make it a `OR` condition too.

```
$query
    ->contain('Items')
    ->leftJoinWith('Items')
    ->where([
        'OR' => [
            'Orders.id' => $freeText,
            // ...
            'Items.vessel_id' => $freeText
        ]
    ])
    ->groupBy('Orders.id');
```

See also

- [**Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Filtering by Associated Data**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#filtering-by-associated-data)
- [**Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Using leftJoinWith**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-leftjoinwith)